# How can I match words regardless of tense or form?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, string-matching

I am currently working on a script that runs through a document, pulls out all keywords, and then attempts to match these keywords with those found in other documents. There are some specifics that complicate this, but they are not very pertinent to me question. Basically I would like to be able to match words regardless of the tense in which they appear.

For example: If given the strings "swim", "swam", and "swimming", I would like a program that can recognize that these are all the same word, though whether it would store the word as swim, swam or swimming doesn't matter all that much to me.

I'm aware that this problem could be mostly solved with a dictionary containing all of these word forms, but I am unaware of any dictionary that is mapped in such a way to be useful for this. I would prefer a solution or library that is compatible with Python, since that is what I am currently using for this scripting, but I would be fine with a solution in just about any language (save haskell or eiffel or something similarly obscure/difficult to work with)

Comment: Added a tag for NLTK, the Python toolkit for NLP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [pywordnet](https://web.archive.org/web/20180811040419/http://osteele.com/projects/pywordnet).

```
>>> N['dog']
dog(n.)
>>> N['dog'].getSenses()
('dog' in {noun: dog, domestic dog, Canis familiaris},
 'dog' in {noun: frump, dog}, 'dog' in {noun: dog},
 'dog' in {noun: cad, bounder, blackguard, dog, hound, heel},
 'dog' in {noun: pawl, detent, click, dog},
 'dog' in {noun: andiron, firedog, dog, dogiron})
```

---

Edit: This library was discontinued in 2006 when it was merged into [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/)

Comment: Thanks for this! Probably worth noting that pywordnet is no longer updated or supported by wordnet, but this did lead me to the natural language toolkit, which is.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Your correct.  pywordnet is part of the NLTK now.  Glad it helped(if your happy with the answer don't forget to accept it by clicking on the little check mark below the voting area beside this answer)

Comment: I am surprised this answer really helped. WordNet's stemming/lemmatization capabilities are *very* limited (for example, it resolves none of your examples, 'swimming' etc. correctly to its lemma or stem). I also tried the other stemmers built into NLTK, both in code and in the [online demo](http://text-processing.com/demo/stem/), and did not find them to work well with some standard verbs (e.g. try 'walked'), nor with your examples. Finally, the code snippet given in the answer is about semantic relations, not inflectional forms.

Comment: That may be true for the standard lemmitization provided in Wordnet, but nltk also implements the lancaster stemming algorithm that aggressively resolves words to a basic stem, and though it may not be a word in and of itself, it will resolve all those things above to the same entry.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it sounds like you're looking for a **stemming** or **lemmatization** algorithm, which essentially maps each word to its dictionary form. One well-known such algorithm is the Porter Stemming algorithm, which has been around for three decades and has implementations in a variety of languages, including Python. You can find a list of these implementations at http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/ .

While the Porter stemmer's been around a long time and can be useful for comparison reasons, Spaceghost correctly points out that this isn't necessarily the best system available. [Snowball](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/english/stemmer.html) is supposed to be better than the Porter stemming algorithm.

Comment: Porter himself suggests that this is "slightly inferior" to Snowball, http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/english/stemmer.html

Answer (score 0):

This problem you describe appears to be a Stemming problem, they are some useful stemmers out there like the porter stemmer. More specifically try implement it using the nltk tool kit for Python which if im not mistaken comes with a porter stemmer.